# What is the name of the song beginning at 2:47?

Tags: identify-this-song, piano

what is that song's name from 2:47?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

"The Entertainer", by Scott Joplin.

Comment: By answering questions like this one, it encourages other similar questions, which goes against the grain on this site, not meeting the guidelines. I love the way he counts in a 3/4 tune: 1,2,3,4... And that apart - he actually says 'the Entertainer'!!

Comment: @Tim It's been flagged to migrate to Music Fans.

Comment: Hadn't finished the comment!

Comment: @Tim: Seems I should have listened to more of the video.

Comment: Not you - but the OP...